# Can Azure WebJob consist only of console app or should be built only using JobHost for running on demand?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I'm building a job to sync some Azure AD data. It should be running every hour. For that purpose I'm thinking if I need to add JobHost implementation or it is enough to have just a ConsoleApp with settings.job file having schedule and added as a job?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for delay. Yes, it worked. Just deployed today and had a chance to test that. I have configured schedule using settings.job file as I mentioned before and it was successfully picked in azure devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

You can create console app and build it, then you can include the generated .exe file / other .dll files into a .zip file. Then upload the .zip file to azure webjob.

For Supported file types, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#acceptablefiles).

For create a scheduled webjob, please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON). And a screenshot on how to create a scheduled webjobs:

[image]